# Seeing HTML source changes after javascript has acted upon it, in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an HTML document with inline javascript which adds some `<div>` elements. The elements appear on the screen, but I can't see any change in the HTML source after the elements have been added. I use the latest version of chrome, and I do "View" -> "Page Source".

Seeing changes in the HTML would really help for debugging!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right-click on the element and select "inspect element"

Comment: This doesn't show the raw html as it is received from the web server. It is already parsed by Chrome.

Comment: There is a network tab in there which shows the response received from server.

Comment: @Albert that was the question. It looks like html to me, you can easily copy the 'processed' html elements into a notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Use firebug when using Firefox
For Chrome there is built in tool(use Ctrl+Shift+I)

Comment: sorry for the confusion,
here is the link for firebug
[link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score -1):

Use Firefox, install web developer and choose "view source"=>"view generated source"