# View source not available in some browsers for dynamically created webpage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dynamic

CONTEXT

I am creating an  http://canvimation.github.com/ that uses javascript to create web pages dynamically.

The source code for my application is at https://github.com/canvimation/canvimation.github.com

The application uses Canvas to draw using vector objects the resulting drawing can then be exported as a web page.  To create a web page click on the FILE icon and then 'Export Canvas to HTML'.

The exporting code opens a new window and uses document.writenl() to construct the code. The relevant function is shown at the end of the question.

All browsers I have tried produce the drawing correctly in the new window as a web page. In all browsers view source shows the expected code for the application web page.

In IE10 and Firefox it is possible to view the source of the exported code which can then be saved and the saved file used as a webpage.

For the exported web page: in Chrome 28 view source is greyed out and not available; in Safari 5 for Windows view source produces a blank window and in Opera 12 source does not do anything.

QUESTIONS

1. How is it possible to save or view the source of the exported webpage in Chrome, Safari and Opera?
2. Can anything be changed in my method to dynamically create a webpage that can have its source code viewed and saved?

RELEVANT CODE

```
function exportShapes()
{   
    var shapelist=[];
    var nameZ=[];
    for (var name in SHAPES)
    {
        nameZ=[];
        nameZ.push(name);
        nameZ.push(SHAPES[name].zIndex);
        shapelist.push(nameZ);
    }
    shapelist.sort(compareZ);

    newwindow=window.open('','export');
    newwindow.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE HTML>');
    newwindow.document.writeln('<html>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,3)+'<head>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'<style>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,9)+'#canvasarea');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,9)+'{');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'border:black 1px solid;');
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,9)+'}');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'</style>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'<!--[IF LT IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src = "excanvas.js" ></script><![endif]-->');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'<script type="text/javascript">');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,9)+'function setcanvas()');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,9)+'{');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasarea");');  
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'if (canvas.getContext)');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'{');  
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,15)+'var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,15)+'drawcanvas(ctx);');
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,12)+'}'); 
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'else');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,12)+'{');  
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,15)+'alert("Canvas NOT supported");');   
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,12)+'}'); 
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,9)+'}');
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,9));
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,9)+'function drawcanvas(ctx)');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,9)+'{');
    for(var i=0;i<shapelist.length;i++)
    {
        exportshape(shapelist[i][0]);
    }   
    newwindow.document.writeln (SPACES.substr(0,9)+'}');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'</script>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,3)+'</head>');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,3)+'<body onload="setcanvas()">');
    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,6)+'<canvas id="canvasarea" width="'+parseInt($("stagearea").style.width)+'" height="'+parseInt($("stagearea").style.height)+'"></canvas>');     

    newwindow.document.writeln(SPACES.substr(0,3)+'</body>');
    newwindow.document.writeln('</html>');
    newwindow.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to see the HTML after javascript rendering, then right-click > inspect element should let you see the code, at least in Chrome.

You should then be able to copy it manually - or do you need it to be done automatically?

I know in brython it's just in the variable `doc.html`, but that probably doesn't help you in javascript.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868577/seeing-html-source-changes-after-javascript-has-acted-upon-it-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I had not though of that at all. This does work in Chrome, Opera and Safari. My concern is that as I wanted to make the application as easy to use as possible this method requires the user to: select inspect element-->right click <HTML> tag-->Copy to HTML-->paste in text editor-->write in <!DOCTYPE html> at start of text. At the moment I will see what other answers I receive. Thanks again.

Comment: Have just re-read above comment and realised it could sound sarcastic and it's too late to edit. I genuinely hadn't thought of inspect element and went straight to give it a go.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this in javascript.  I know there's a way to do it in brython, so there has to be a way to do it in javascript - though my knowledge of JS is somewhat limited.

Comment: This answers my question 1 and further searches have convinced me it is the only way to achieve this, so I have gratefully accepted the answer. I intend to add a method whereby the HTML code is also output within a textarea so that the source code for the created web page is easily accessible for copying for all browsers.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to help with the JS method to help you.  Feel free to edit my answer with the simple method for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's a blank page (about:blank), for which Chrome sees no reason to view the source code, because it should be empty. You may consider creating some sort of temp file and put all the canvas stuff into it.

Inspect Element option, suggested above, doesn't work in this case, it's not going beyond canvas tag. I suspect Chrome is rendering this as a picture, not as a vector graphics.

Comment: Any way of stopping it being a blank page. By the way have found a way of saving the whole of the code except doctype when using inspect element - see my comment to Paul.