# Why can't React elements be seen with "view source"

Tags: reactjs

When I view the source of my React app I only see the boilerplate index file.

I thought Dom elements were being created / destroyed / updated / etc...

How come I can't see all these divs, spans, h1's etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing HTML source changes after javascript has acted upon it, in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868577/seeing-html-source-changes-after-javascript-has-acted-upon-it-in-chrome)

Comment: All the changes that are introduced using React JS are done on the client side by JavaScript, so you won't be able to see them in the View Source, which comes from the server.

Answer (score 4):

React has it's own "internal DOM" which it uses to manage state and injects the "real" elements into the main DOM using JavaScript after the page has loaded.

If you do want to view them however, you can use the React development plugin for Chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Just install, inspect element and then traverse to the React tab of dev tools.

Comment: I think the answer is a combination of "view source" just gives me what the server returns. To see "all the changes made" by React just use "inspect" instead of "view source". The current state of the Dom is there.

Comment: Also, I do have the chrome extension installed. I just thought for some reason "view source" was going to give me the current Dom... nope.... but "inspect" will.